# What is BigQuery DML Quota restriction

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I was under impression that BigQuery DML has no longer INERT restriction, however, one of my ingestion workflows that runs INSERT DML uniformly distributed across the day, on average 80 DML every 2 min (~35-70B records transformations and aggregation per day) failed occasionally.

What's strange I am seeing only a few INSERT DML queries failed and only for some hours. When looking at pending jobs, around when errors took place there are no more than a few queries job in the pending state.  All DML queries use the reservation.

I wonder what is and how the quota is computed, besides that [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/dml-without-limits-now-in-bigquery) claims there is no DML INSERT quota.

Here is the error I am seeing.
{"location":"max_dml_outstanding_per_table","message":"Quota exceeded: Your table exceeded quota for total number of dml jobs writing to a table, pending + running. For more information, see [https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors","reason":"quotaExceeded"}](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors%22,%22reason%22:%22quotaExceeded%22%7D)

To better understand my case, I am using [bqtail](https://github.com/viant/bqtail) ingestion workflow defined as:

```
When:
  Prefix: "/xxxxx/xxxx/"
  Suffix: ".gz"
Async: true
Batch:
  MultiPath: true
  Window:
    DurationInSec: 120

Dest:
  Pattern: '.+/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/.+'
  Table: myproject.selector.selection_$Mod(80)_$1$2$3
  SourceFormat: NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
  Transient:
    Dataset: temp
    Balancer:
      MaxLoadJobs: 100
      ProjectIDs:
        - myproject-transient1
        - myproject-transient2
        - myproject-transient3
        - myproject-transient4
        - myproject-transient5
  Schema:
    Template: myproject.selector.selection_tmpl
  SchemaUpdateOptions:
    - ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION
  WriteDisposition: WRITE_APPEND

OnSuccess:
  - Action: query
    Request:
      SQL: INSERT INTO `myproject.selector.xxx_agg1`( ....) SELECT ... FROM $TempTable GROUP BY x, y, z
    OnSuccess:
      - Action: query
        Request:
          SQL: INSERT INTO `myproject.selector.xxx_agg2`( ....) SELECT ... FROM $TempTable GROUP BY x1, y1, z1
        OnSuccess:
          - Action: delete
```

In summary: every two minutes data files are batched upto 80 load requests into transient tables and then copied to the final destination tables: myproject.selector.selection_$Mod(80)_$1$2$3  (80 different tables suffixed by date).

Ingestion work is distributed between 5 transient projects, the typical batch would be up to 1M records, each load job taking around 22 sec and copy job taking 1 sec.  After a successful copy, the first DML executes, then the second.

Comment: Do you know the volume of data in each insert?

Comment: It produces 15B records per day on one of the aggregated table, so it would be 262721 inserted record per each DML job, usually, the job runs between  6 - 17 sec

Comment: How many DML insert are you performing on the same table on each DML job (every 2 minutes)?

Comment: up to 80, as in the description, it is implemented across 5 transient projects,  (20 DML per project all going to one  final dest table)

Answer (score 2):

As per GCP support team. The error message indicated that DML jobs were hitting DML_ALL_JOBS_CONCURRENT limit.

DML_ALL_JOBS_CONCURRENT is not a numbered limit itself, it just gets triggered when either the INSERT concurrency limit or the UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE concurrency limit has been reached.

DML INSERT allows up to 100 concurrent jobs (pending+running) per table.
DML MERGE/UPDATE/DELTE up 20 concurrent jobs (pending+running) per table.

Answer (score 1):

This quota error means you're submitting jobs faster than they can be finished by BigQuery. BigQuery can only run a certain number of DML jobs concurrently on a table (running jobs). When jobs are received after this limit is exceeded, the jobs are put into a queue to wait for execution (pending jobs). When limit of this queue is also exceeded, you receive this quota error, "Your table exceeded quota for total number of dml jobs writing to a table, pending + running".

Retry the submission of these jobs, with exponential backoff, should help in this situation.

The streaming API is another option for frequent, small appends to the table. It allows for a much higher QPS.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I want to avoid the complexity and high cost of streaming API, for now, it is exploring event-driven data consumption, as data arrived at BigQuery, with post-ingestion SQL based transformation. It is good to know BigQuery restriction. Especially when planning for  500B+ transaction target per day.  Luckily DML INSERT is not a blocker, I can achieve the same aggregation, transformation with extra export, and load pipeline chaining actions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your comment, you should reach one limit. When you look at the [quotas documentation for DML you can read this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#data_manipulation_language_statements)

> BigQuery DML statements have no quota limits.

> However, DML statements are counted toward the maximum number of table operations per day and partition modifications per day. DML statements will not fail due to these limits.

> In addition, DML statements are subject to the maximum rate of table metadata update operations. If you exceed this limit, retry the operation using exponential backoff between retries.

If you follow the latest link, on the [table metadata update operation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#standard_tables), you have this

> Maximum rate of table metadata update operations — 5 operations every 10 seconds per table

> The table metadata update limit includes all metadata update operations performed by using the Cloud Console, the classic BigQuery web UI, the bq command-line tool, the client libraries, by calling the tables.insert, tables.patch, or tables.update API methods, or executing ALTER TABLE DDL statements. This limit also applies to job output.

---

So, in summary, you perform more than 5 tables insert `tables.insert` over 10 secondes and you have an issue with an retry exponential backoff.

Sometime the quota is tolerant, sometime it reject you! This can depend on the global platform status.

Try to insert is only 1 request in the same table (you can use temp table and then perform a global insert query over all these temp tables)

Comment: There should be no metadata limit applied I am not using any of your listed operation (DDL, tables.insert, tables.patch, or tables.update)

Comment: I have read BQ documentation,  and the only thing that can explain this behavior is the DML concurrency limit:  that after 1K operation is reduced to 10, but event, in this case, I would not see more than few pending jobs

Comment: As referrecnce:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#concurrent_jobs

Comment: All in all, I do not see explanation for the quota error

Comment: You might ask directly the Google Cloud Support for more precise information. If you haven't a paid support, you can open an issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/) (without commitment on the answer delay)

Comment: Thanks, I had already raised the issue and shared the response, and 100 limit makes sense, at least that what I was suspecting, since this is intermittent issue a few jobs fails over thousands per day, I am following on reservation aspect, thanks for the response.